# Books/tutorials on programming a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, rs232, books, lpc

I'm relatively new to programming with Microcontrollers. I bought an LPC1313 MCU and an FTDI RS232 cable from newark. I later found out that I would need to construct a PCB with 6 pin headers inorder to make the MCU interface properly with the cable. I have no idea how to make that. Are there any books or resources that I can read or look at to get an idea of how to make that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick 1:

1. Buy an [evaluation board](http://www.keil.com/mcb1000/)
2. Buy a suitable break-out board for the package purchased
   [E.g.](http://www.nkcelectronics.com/lqfp48-breakout-boa48.html)
3. Buy a generic proto board with suitable footprint.
   [Maybe?](http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_qfp&id=66)
4. Put the LPC1313 to one side, buy an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and use that instead.
   as Brian K suggests in a comment below.

The Arduino suggestion, though in many ways similar to the first option above, is a good one in that there is a very large community of Arduino users who provide support to people new to electronics.

Comment: That is one of the most helpful answers I have heard in a long time. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Buy an Arduino and get started with that.

Comment: Or buy an MSP430, or an STM32 Discovery, or a Raspberry Pi, or a PIC board... Arduinos are not the be-all and end-all of MCU's, and I'd say they are actually poor value & teach a relatively poor style of programming compared to using C on an MSP or STM32 etc.